# How to set spent time by commit message on Youtrack Time Tracking?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, youtrack, time-tracking

I am using Youtrack Standalone version, and I enabled Time Tracking feature in Intellij IDEA. Also I installed Youtrack plugin.

I can set spent time manually in Time Tracking panel, by pressing "Post work item to bugtracker". This is pretty good, but I want this to be done by git commit message like in the following format:

{id} {summary}

{time}

**id** - Id of an issue
**summary** - summary of an issue
**time** - spent time of the task or commit

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure either [VCS](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.3/Integration-with-Version-Control-Systems.html) or [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.3/Integration-with-TeamCity.html) or [Upsource](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.3/Integration-with-Upsource.html) integration in YouTrack.
After you're done with configuration you'll be able to use issue a commit in format `#Id command`. The command can look like `work 1d doing stuff` which will create a workitem in the issue.

Comment: It works, but there is one more thing. After pushing it is adding workitem in issue, but not setting time to zero in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure commit message in "Settings | Tools | Tasks | Servers - Commit Message"

Comment: I have configured already. But when push commit it is not tracking time.

Comment: What do you get when you use {time} in commit message?

Comment: {time} shows spent time in commit, but after pushing I want Youtrack server to set spent time on issue Time Tracking section.

Comment: Feel  free to create request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Thanks for link. I will create request.